# 502 Bad Gateway Error when using jQuery Ajax POST with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to send data to a database. Here is the method I am using:

```
<script>

function add_new_activity(id) {

    var act_type = $("#add_new_activity #act_type").val();
    var act_muscles = $("#add_new_activity #multi").val();
    var act_location = $("#add_new_activity #act_location").val();
    var act_intensity = $("#add_new_activity #act_intensity").val();
    var act_length = $("#add_new_activity #timepicker").val();
    var act_content = $("#add_new_activity #textarea").val();                                                           
    if(act_type != "" && act_muscles != "" && act_location != ""  && act_intensity != "" && act_content != ""){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "data.php",
            data: "page=profile&add_new_activity=<?php echo $user->user_id; ?>&act_type="+act_type+"&act_muscles="+act_muscles+"&act_location="+act_location+"&act_intensity="+act_intensity+"&act_length="+act_length+"&act_content="+act_content,
            success: function(data){
               location.reload();
            },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#add_new_activity #add_act_button").html("<?php echo $translate->_('adding'); ?>...");
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("#add_new_activity #message").html("<div class='alert alert-error'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'></button><?php echo $translate->_('required_field'); ?></div>");
    }
}
</script>
```

part of **`data.php`**

```
if(isset($_POST['add_new_activity'])){
    $user_id = $_POST['add_new_activity'];
    $act_type = $_POST['act_type'];
    $act_muscles = $_POST['act_muscles'];
    $act_location = $_POST['act_location'];
    $act_intensity = $_POST['act_intensity'];
    $act_length = $_POST['act_length'];
    $act_content = $_POST['act_content'];                                                                                                                                           
    Profile::add_new_activity($user_id, $act_type, $act_muscles, $act_location, $act_intensity, $act_length, $act_content);}
```

part of **`Profile`** class

```
public static function add_new_activity($user_id, $act_type, $act_muscles, $act_location, $act_intensity, $act_length, $act_content,$user_id=""){
    global $database;
    global $translate;

    $datetime = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time());
    $database->query("INSERT INTO activities (id,type,body,intensity,location,content,length,posted,user_id) VALUES ('','{$act_type}','{$act_muscles}','{$act_intensity}','{$act_location}','{$act_content}','{$act_length}','{$datetime}','{$user_id}') ");

}
```

If I post a small amount of data everything is ok, but if I post a large amount I get this error:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**`server log:`**

```
ip - - [17/Jan/2014:00:02:00 +0100] "POST /fitstats/data.php HTTP/1.1" 200 537 "http://ssbox.si/fitstats/profile.php?lang=en&username=some1ell" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"
```

How can I pass these error and successfully send data to mysql?

Comment: What do your server error logs say

Comment: I updated my question with server log that I am able to access

Comment: That looks like your apache access.log, you need the error.log

Comment: I can't get it :/ I can only access to access.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: It's been a while since I've done anything in web world.

As for an approach to spsc_tech's answer:

I generally like to wrap my data into an object like so:

```
function add_new_activity(id) {
    var act_type = $("#add_new_activity #act_type").val();
    var act_muscles = $("#add_new_activity #multi").val();
    var act_location = $("#add_new_activity #act_location").val();
    var act_intensity = $("#add_new_activity #act_intensity").val();
    var act_length = $("#add_new_activity #timepicker").val();
    var act_content = $("#add_new_activity #textarea").val();                                                           
    if(act_type != "" && act_muscles != "" && act_location != ""  && act_intensity != "" && act_content != ""){
        var theData = {};
        theData['page'] = 'profile';
        theData['add_new_activity'] = '<?php echo $user->user_id;?>';
        theData['act_type'] = act_type;
        theData['act_muscles'] = act_muscles;
        theData['act_location'] = act_location;
        theData['act_intensity'] = act_intensity;
        theData['act_length'] = act_length;
        theData['act_content'] = act_content;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "data.php",
            data: theData,
            success: function(result){
               location.reload();
            },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#add_new_activity #add_act_button").html("<?php echo $translate->_('adding'); ?>...");
            }
        });
    } else {
    $("#add_new_activity #message").html("<div class='alert alert-error'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'></button><?php echo $translate->_('required_field'); ?></div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: @SašoKrajnc: What is "Can't get it" to work that way? Is it still giving a 502?

Comment: hmm..it seems like there is some mistake in code but I dont see it..it can't get executed

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4g5mv/ - There doesn't appear to be any errors that I can see. Regardless, you need to be able to debug at least a little bit of Javascript.

Comment: I added it with your code. If you want to debug it, in Chrome, right click and select "Inspect Element". Then you can view the Console to look for errors or go to "Sources" and put breakpoints on lines of javascript.

Comment: sorry...my bad :/ It is late at night and I am not focused anymore =) It is all working now! There was a syntax error by my side.. Thank you!

Comment: being a victim of this error code it happened to me while i was trying to throw a content type header in the middle of my script removing that wiped the error off my request!  So "in case" nothing mentioned here works check for bad header or any header for that matter and see if that is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have characters in your query that are not allowed.  I can clearly see a ton of non-escaped spaces in that query string, for example.  Look up url encoding and decoding in both [php](https://www.php.net/urlencode) and [jquery/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript) and that should solve your problem.